# How do I avoid needing to use parseFloat/Int, number() in the first place with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, parseint, parsefloat

When adding some non-quoted object values, it sometimes concatenates the values instead of actually adding them, so I use the parseInt or parseFloat function around both of the values.

Example:

```
var testobj = 
{

    'test1': 
    {
        'rect': {x:100, y:0, w:0, h:0}
    },

    'line2': 
    {
        'rect': {x:0, y:0, w:200, h:0}
    }

}

var result = parseFloat(testobj['test1'].rect.x) + parseFloat(testObj['test2'].rect.w);

console.log(result); // will give me 300

result = testobj['test1'].rect.x + testObj['test2'].rect.w;

console.log(result); // will give me 100300
```

I find it really annoying that I need to use parseFloat. Any way to get around this?

Comment: both give me 300 ([JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uq9mjLsf/)), are you sure the values are non-quoted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can force the variable to become a number if you use `+` in front of the variable, check the example below.

```js
var testobj = {
    'test1': 
    {
        'rect': {x:'100', y:'0', w:'0', h:'0'}
    },

    'line2': 
    {
        'rect': {x:'0', y:'0', w:'200', h:'0'}
    }
}

var result = +(testobj['test1'].rect.x) + +(testobj['line2'].rect.w);

console.log(result); // will give me 300

result = testobj['test1'].rect.x + testobj['line2'].rect.w;

console.log(result); // will give me 100300
```

```js
var a = '11';
var b = '22';

var c = '1.25';
var d = '2.25';


console.log('"11" + "22" = ' + a + b);
console.log('+"11" + +"22" = ' + (+a + +b));

console.log(+"11" + +"22");

console.log(c + d);
console.log(+c + +d);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write a small function which converts all stringified int/float keys of an obj into int/float, so you don't repeatedly need to take extra measure at the time of calculation.

```
function parseNumKeys(obj) {
    if( typeof obj == "object" ) {
        for(var key in obj){
            var num = parseFloat(obj[key]);
            isNaN(num)? parseNumKeys(obj[key]) : obj[key] = num; 
        }
    }
}
```

Pass your obj to above function:

```
var testobj = {
    'test1': 
    {
        'rect': {x:'100', y:'0', w:'0', h:'0'}
    },

    'line2': 
    {
        'rect': {x:'0', y:'0', w:'200', h:'0'}
    }
} 

console.log("before parseNumKeys called: \n", testobj);

parseNumKeys(testobj);

console.log("after parseNumKeys called: \n", testobj);

// before parseNumKeys called: 
//  { test1: { rect: { x: '100', y: '0', w: '0', h: '0' } },
//   line2: { rect: { x: '0', y: '0', w: '200', h: '0' } } }
// after parseNumKeys called: 
//  { test1: { rect: { x: 100, y: 0, w: 0, h: 0 } },
//   line2: { rect: {   x: 0, y: 0, w: 200, h: 0 } } }
```

Now, `result = testobj['test1'].rect.x + testobj['line2'].rect.w;` will give 300 not 100300, without additional processing.